# Is there an optional type with underlying heap allocation

Tags: c++

Is there a type, in the C++ standard library, whose semantics are the same as `optional`, but whose underlying value is stored on the heap? Is there such a type in boost? If not, how would you implement this behavior?

I want to make tree structs with RAII managed branches, and value semantics, like so:

```
struct tree{
    int val;
    heap_optional<tree> left;
    heap_optional<tree> right;
};
```

Edit:

The idea is the optional would have an assignment operator on `lvalue` references. The above struct, with default assignment, would work as is with no extra implementation. If I use `std::unique_ptr` it only has move assignment, so I would have to implement all of the assignment operators and friends in the containing struct.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<tree> left;` ?

Comment: That's funny, when I saw `std::optional` I said "finally something nullable as `unique_ptr` but without having to allocate on heap".

Comment: This would not work.  If copying your `heap_optional<tree>` also made a copy of the heap-allocated storage, those copies would have their own `left` and `right`, pointing back to branches on the wrong tree.

Comment: @Drew Dormann If you implemented the optional to copy the underlying contained value, and not the pointer, then it would trigger the default assignment of the contained nodes, which would then trigger their optional assignments recursively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` is what you are looking for.

Comment: But `std::unique_ptr` doesn't copy it's underlying value when you assign it to something else.

Comment: @Polymer Why would you want to do that for a binary tree node?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth To make the tree have value semantics. So I can have tree a = b work with the default assignment operators.

Comment: @Polymer You do a lot of copying/assignment of trees? I don't think I've ever needed to do that.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth Sure, suppose I have a logical document or report, represented as a tree. Maybe I want to swap the location of paragraphs, or copy a paragraph before modifying it. Swapping the nodes, or copying the nodes and inserting them in the proper spot could be useful.

Comment: @Polymer I don't see you need anything other than pointers to do that.

Comment: @Polymer: `std::swap` should work fine, for copy create a function that creates a new `std::unique_ptr` and copies the content of the other one. you can also `std::move` a  `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I was trying to justify the use of the semantics. Of course I could implement the required functionality in operator= with an underlying pointer. But I want the compiler to do it for me. The point is that I could easily define multiple recursive structs which won't behave in surprising ways with other language features that depend on value semantics; Simply by using this sort of optional.

Comment: if you want a tree with value semantics, use std::map, it's a red black tree.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the sort of device I'm looking for is called `value_ptr`, `clone_ptr` or `copy_ptr`. It seems people intuitively want copying pointers to be a cheap operation, or to always mean pointer assignment. I'm leaving the most upvoted answer as the correct one.

Edit:

There is apparently on and off discussion for a feature like this by the standards committee. https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/YnUvKJATgD0

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of `value_ptr`. I'm implementing a generic tree-like container where the nodes can have empty values, and I don't want those nodes to waste much space. I want to dynamically allocate values if they are large, or just use optional<T> if they are small. `value_ptr<T>` is just what I need if the values are large. I've already accidentally implemented my own `value_ptr`, so I guess now I know what to name it.